# How To Get Link(href) Value using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have been working on an desktop application and i am struct on getting the href value of the links.I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse the webpages.
here is the code

```
int count=0;
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='ann123']//table"))
            {

            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
                {
                    if ((count % 2 == 0))
                    {
                        dr["Name"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HtmlAttribute att = cell.Attributes["href"];

                        dr["Value"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + att.Value;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

This code gives me an error on trying to print "att.Value" in dr["Value"]. If i remove the "att.Value" it prints the text fine. But i want the link too.
When i print the value of "cell.InnerHtml;" i get something like this,

```
<span><a href="uploads/NRI.pdf" target="_blank" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Tahoma; color:#0B2C57;">B.Tech Admission List Under NRI Category 2013-14</a></span>
```

What i want is to get the href value i.e. "uploads/NRI.pdf" as a string and display it as a link in my app and since its a table of links in the html, i want the link of every table entry. 
Something i found similar: [How to get a link's title and href value separately with html agility pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358151/how-to-get-a-links-title-and-href-value-separately-with-html-agility-pack?rq=1)

Help Please Community?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: you are selecting from <td> nodes (that is what `cell` would be pointing at) - so getting the "href" Attribute will probably return a null... you should be looking at the <a> tag instead.

Comment: so.. should i be using "td//a" in xpath. if you want to look you can look at this table at http://www.jiet.ac.in/. its the announcements table.

Comment: maybe this would work? `string url= cell.Element("a").GetAttributeValue("href","unknown");`